# Limits of hashes comparisons

Tags: python, hash

I'm storing hash codes in a file, one hash per line.

When I have a new hash code, I open the file and check if
the hash code already exists and if it doesn't exist,
I save it to that file.

```
f = open("hashes.txt", "w")
hashes = f.readlines()
hash_code = "ff071fdf1e060400"
if not hash_code in hashes:
  hashes.append(hash_code)
for h in hashes:
  f.write(h)
f.close()
```

This code may be slow, when the number of lines in hashes.txt grows.
Is there some better storage mechanism and check to make it faster
in that case? I need fastest possible check (within a few seconds).

Comment: you open the file as write everytime? Can't you keep `hashes` in memory? You could do `hashes = set(f.readlines())` for better speed. But the file reading everytime is really a speed problem.

Comment: Do you need to write all hashes out again? Can't you just append the new one to the file?

Comment: Use a  database system such as SQLite

Comment: Why are you opening the file for _writing_, and then _reading_ from it?

Comment: @UnholySheep  Yes, I can open for appending. Actually I was considering if it's better for the hashes to be sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It should be list without duplicate values, already.

Comment: `set(f.readlines())` includes an unnecessary readlines call, `set(f)` would do the same thing but both would include newlines as does your own code which is wrong. How large do you think the file is going to get? Also are you checking numerous hashes on each run or what exactly is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
class Hashes(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        with open(filename, 'rt') as f:             # read the file only once
            self.hashes = set(line.strip() for line in f)

    def add_hash(self, hash):
        if hash not in self.hashes:                 # this is very fast with sets
            self.hashes.add(hash)
            with open(self.filename, 'at') as f:
                print(hash, file=f)                 # write only one hash

hashes = Hashes("hashes.txt")
hashes.add_hash("ff071fdf1e060400")
```

Because:

- the file is read only once
- checking whether a hash exists is very fast with sets (no need to read all of them)
- hashes are added by writing only the new hash
- the class simplifies creation of mutiple hash files and cleanup of cached hashes, and it simplifies maintenance by organising the code

The downside is that all hashes are kept in memory. If there are many millions of hashes, that could start causing problems, but until then it is fine. It is better than fine, if speed is important.

Comment: `print(hash, file=f)` `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @xralf `print(hash, file=f)` is valid in Python 3. In Python 2, `print >>f, hash` does the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with Bert on this. If you expect that there will be a lot of hashes it would be better to use a database. If this only happens locally a sqlite database is fine. There is an excellent orm library that works for sqlite; [Peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/). It got some excellent documentation that will get you started.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with SQLite. Is that because of indexing? Isn't it little big scenario to create a database with one table and one column for this purpose? Is it because of index, I can create for that column? I can't achieve it with a file?

Comment: Well, if you want something that scales to many entries, like a million or more. SQLite would be the way to go. Otherwise a file might work equally well. And yes, the reason why sqlite is fast is because of indexing. You won't be able to get that with a file. 

Though, checking things in a set as per the other answer happens in O(1) time, so it's definitely fast. It's reading the file into the system that would take time.

Comment: Apart from the number of total elements, another factor to consider is how often you will be repeating the same analysis. My set solution will re-build an 'index' every time that the program is restarted while the sqlite database can be re-read more efficiently on the second, third, and so on start. Jonathan's solution will scale better in cases of very many hashes and many restarts.

Answer (score 1):

A [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set) can be used for fast membership lookups. Since files can be used as an iterator, passing an open file handle to the set constructor will read entries into the set by line without first filling an intermediate in-memory array.

After this, you can simply use the set difference `-` operator to efficiently check which hashes are new and the union operator `|` to add the newly found elements to the list of known hashes:

```
# at program start, init list of known hashes
# open hashes_in.txt, read line by line and add to set
# set removes duplicate elements
with open("hashes.txt", "r") as f:
    hashes = set(f)

# as new hashes are encountered, use this to check if they have been seen before
def compare_hashes(search_hashes, hashes):
    search_hashes = set(search_hashes)

    # find new hashes
    new_hashes = search_hashes - hashes

    # update list of known hashes
    hashes |= new_hashes

    # write out new hashes
    with open("hashes.txt", "a") as f:
        for h in new_hashes:
            f.write(h)

    return new_hashes, hashes



with open("hashes2.txt", "r") as f:
    new_hashes, hashes = compare_hashes(f, hashes)
    print(new_hashes)
```

This answer assumes that both your list of known entries and search entries will come from files and thus have trailing newlines that will be part of the matching. If this is not what you want, you can strip newlines for a small performance overhead:

```
strip_newlines = lambda hashes: (h.strip() for h in hashes)
```

Use it like so:

```
hashes = set(strip_newlines(f))
new_hashes, hashes = compare_hashes(strip_newlines(f), hashes)
```

Comment: The point is that the file hashes.txt should contain already unique hashes. And my code should check if some new hashcode (of object downloaded from web) is in the file hashes.txt

Comment: Sets can also be used for constant-time membership checks. You can check `hash_code in hashes` to see if a hash `hash_code` is in the `hashes` set or, as in the updated code above, use the set difference to check for new entries.

Comment: You are including newlines so I doubt you will ever find matches even for existing matches. Also set.difference would  avoid an unnecessary set creation.

Comment: Yes, the entries include newlines, but since both the needle and haystack entries have trailing newlines they will match. Regarding the set.difference, I have to compute `search_hashes - hashes` so that in order to do `search_hashes.difference(hashes)`, `search_hashes` has to be a set. Do you have an idea how to get around this?

Comment: Added a comment about stripping newlines.